# Selecting <li> elements with specific attribute values between two <li> elements also with specific attributes

Tags: html, xslt, xpath

I am working with some pretty messy HTML source content and trying to structure a single ol into one where attributes (from the source) determine if certain list items should be put into their own sub-list. The list is also broken up into several ol, but I think that can be gotten around by ignoring the parent node.

Source:

```
<div class="x-popup-text c3" id="POPUP172050488">
  <p>To add multiple balance adjustments:</p>
  <ol>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Check 
      <span class="hcp1">Add to queue</span> at the bottom of the page.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">At the top of the page, enter the 
      <span class="hcp1">Account</span>. &#160;This is a three-part field:</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">In the first part, select the bank number &#160;from the drop-down list.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">In the second part, select the application code from the drop-down list.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">In the third part, enter the account number or click the account search button 
      <img src="../mag_glass_blue_bkgrd.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16" height="16" border="0" class="hcp2 c1" /> to find it.</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol start="3">
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Enter the start date for the adjustment in the 
      <span class="hcp1">From</span> field or click the calendar button 
      <img src="../calendar.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16" height="18" border="0" class="hcp2 c2" /> to select the date.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Enter the end date for the adjustment in the 
      <span class="hcp1">Through</span> field or click the calendar button 
      <img src="../calendar.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16" height="18" border="0" class="hcp2 c2" /> to select the date.</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p class="StepText">
  <span class="hcp1">Tip:</span> &#160;The Through date must be the same as or after the From date.</p>
  <ol start="5">
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">For each balance you want to adjust, do the following:</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">In the table at the bottom of the page, find the appropriate 
      <span class="hcp1">Balance Type</span> for the adjustment.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">Enter the 
      <span class="hcp1">Amount</span> of the adjustment to the right of the balance type.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">If you want the adjustment to appear on the customer's statement, check the 
      <span class="hcp1">Print on Statements</span> checkbox that corresponds to the adjustment amount you entered.</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol start="6">
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Click 
      <span class="hcp1">Add</span>.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Repeat steps 2 through 7 for each additional adjustment you want to add.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Click the 
      <span class="hcp1">View queue</span> link at the bottom of the page to enter the Work Queue and apply the adjustments.</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I know, it's a mess.

So, essentially: 
Any li with @class='kadov-p-CStep' should be a first-level li. 
Any following-sibling li with @class='kadov-p-CStepBullet' before the next 'kadov-p-Step' li should go in a subordinate list underneath its new parent.

Elsewhere on here, I found a formula for selecting a node-set intersection:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2)=count($ns2)]
```

Which I have tried to follow in my own (probably very confused) way:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="following::li[contains(./@class,'CStepBullet')][count(.|following-sibling::li[not(contains(./@class,'Bullet'))][1]/preceding-sibling::li[contains(./@class,'CStepBullet')]) = count(following-sibling::li[not(contains(./@class,'Bullet'))][1]/preceding-sibling::li[contains(./@class,'CStepBullet')])] ">
```

This currently produces no results in the output XML. I'm also sure it's needlessly overengineered.

Thanks for looking, and in advance for any advice you can offer!

Comment: Sorry, just getting in to the office. Your answer was extremely useful -- I'll need to figure out how to use keys in my use-case, but that's exactly what I needed: a push in the right direction. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="li[@class='kadov-p-CStepBullet']"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::li[@class='kadov-p-CStep'][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="li[@class='kadov-p-CStep']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vFollowing" select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>

    <xsl:if test="$vFollowing">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vFollowing" mode="inGroup"/>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="li[@class='kadov-p-CStepBullet']"/>

 <xsl:template match="li[@class='kadov-p-CStepBullet']" mode="inGroup">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<div class="x-popup-text c3" id="POPUP172050488">
  <p>To add multiple balance adjustments:</p>
  <ol>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Check
      <span class="hcp1">Add to queue</span> at the bottom of the page.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">At the top of the page, enter the
      <span class="hcp1">Account</span>. &#160;This is a three-part field:</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">In the first part, select the bank number &#160;from the drop-down list.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">In the second part, select the application code from the drop-down list.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">In the third part, enter the account number or click the account search button
      <img src="../mag_glass_blue_bkgrd.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16" height="16" border="0" class="hcp2 c1" /> to find it.</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol start="3">
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Enter the start date for the adjustment in the
      <span class="hcp1">From</span> field or click the calendar button
      <img src="../calendar.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16" height="18" border="0" class="hcp2 c2" /> to select the date.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Enter the end date for the adjustment in the
      <span class="hcp1">Through</span> field or click the calendar button
      <img src="../calendar.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16" height="18" border="0" class="hcp2 c2" /> to select the date.</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p class="StepText">
  <span class="hcp1">Tip:</span> &#160;The Through date must be the same as or after the From date.</p>
  <ol start="5">
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">For each balance you want to adjust, do the following:</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">In the table at the bottom of the page, find the appropriate
      <span class="hcp1">Balance Type</span> for the adjustment.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">Enter the
      <span class="hcp1">Amount</span> of the adjustment to the right of the balance type.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
      <p class="StepBullet">If you want the adjustment to appear on the customer's statement, check the
      <span class="hcp1">Print on Statements</span> checkbox that corresponds to the adjustment amount you entered.</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol start="6">
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Click
      <span class="hcp1">Add</span>.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Repeat steps 2 through 7 for each additional adjustment you want to add.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
      <p class="Step">Click the
      <span class="hcp1">View queue</span> link at the bottom of the page to enter the Work Queue and apply the adjustments.</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<div class="x-popup-text c3" id="POPUP172050488">
   <p>To add multiple balance adjustments:</p>
   <ol>
      <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
         <p class="Step">Check
      <span class="hcp1">Add to queue</span> at the bottom of the page.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
         <p class="Step">At the top of the page, enter the
      <span class="hcp1">Account</span>.  This is a three-part field:</p>
         <ul>
            <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
               <p class="StepBullet">In the first part, select the bank number  from the drop-down list.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
               <p class="StepBullet">In the second part, select the application code from the drop-down list.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
               <p class="StepBullet">In the third part, enter the account number or click the account search button
      <img src="../mag_glass_blue_bkgrd.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16"
                       height="16"
                       border="0"
                       class="hcp2 c1"/> to find it.</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <ol start="3">
      <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
         <p class="Step">Enter the start date for the adjustment in the
      <span class="hcp1">From</span> field or click the calendar button
      <img src="../calendar.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16" height="18" border="0"
                 class="hcp2 c2"/> to select the date.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
         <p class="Step">Enter the end date for the adjustment in the
      <span class="hcp1">Through</span> field or click the calendar button
      <img src="../calendar.gif" x-maintain-ratio="TRUE" width="16" height="18" border="0"
                 class="hcp2 c2"/> to select the date.</p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <p class="StepText">
      <span class="hcp1">Tip:</span>  The Through date must be the same as or after the From date.</p>
   <ol start="5">
      <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
         <p class="Step">For each balance you want to adjust, do the following:</p>
         <ul>
            <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
               <p class="StepBullet">In the table at the bottom of the page, find the appropriate
      <span class="hcp1">Balance Type</span> for the adjustment.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
               <p class="StepBullet">Enter the
      <span class="hcp1">Amount</span> of the adjustment to the right of the balance type.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="kadov-p-CStepBullet">
               <p class="StepBullet">If you want the adjustment to appear on the customer's statement, check the
      <span class="hcp1">Print on Statements</span> checkbox that corresponds to the adjustment amount you entered.</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <ol start="6">
      <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
         <p class="Step">Click
      <span class="hcp1">Add</span>.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
         <p class="Step">Repeat steps 2 through 7 for each additional adjustment you want to add.</p>
      </li>
      <li class="kadov-p-CStep">
         <p class="Step">Click the
      <span class="hcp1">View queue</span> link at the bottom of the page to enter the Work Queue and apply the adjustments.</p>
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

Appropriate use of a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to define any `li[@class='kadov-p-CStepBullet']` as a function of its first preceding-sibling `li[@class='kadov-p-CStep']`. Also, proper use of **[modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#modes)**.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#default inGroup">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ol[1]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="li"
                       group-starting-with="li[@class='kadov-p-CStep']">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="inGroup"/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="li[@class='kadov-p-CStep']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

    <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() gt 1]" mode="inGroup"/>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="li[@class='kadov-p-CStepBullet']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)** instruction with the attribute `group-starting-with` and the **[`current-group()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-group)** function. Also, appropriate use of **[modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes)**, the built-ing modes `#current` and `#default` and a list of modes.

Comment: Excellent. Confirmed the general answer worked as desired. My transformation involves selecting the "children" li as part of a for-each loop, but I think I can work out how to do that based on the keys, which I admittedly have not used before.

Thank you!

Comment: @mryeti: I am glad this answer was useful to you. Could you please, *accept this answer (by clicking the check-mark next to it)?

Answer (score 0):

For my specific use-case, I needed to make this part of a for-each loop inside of a `<template match="div">`.

Keys were still the correct answer, so I used this part of the solution style sheet verbatim:

```
 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="li[@class='kadov-p-CStepBullet']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::li[@class='kadov-p-CStep'][1])"/>
```

Then, this portion of my div template processes the kadov-p-CStepBullet `<li>` elements correctly (I am migrating this content to DITA):

```
 <steps>
   <xsl:for-each select="descendant::li[@class='kadov-p-CStep']">
     <xsl:variable name="vFollowing" select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/> 
         <step>
           <cmd>
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </cmd>
           <xsl:if test="following-sibling::li[1][@class='kadov-p-CStepBullet']">
             <info>
               <ul>
               <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::li[$vFollowing]">
                 <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
               </xsl:for-each>
               </ul>
             </info>
           </xsl:if>
         </step>
```

Thank you!